# iAd banner orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

I've implemented to an landscape-oriented application an `iAdBannerView`.

Works fine, but always the full banner view pops-up from the bottom of the device (like from portrait orientation).

Is it possible to make the full banner view pop-up from the bottom of the device on landscape orientation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the code I posted here. It might help you.

[My answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24536352/1627959