# How to integrate iAd in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I have been implementing iAd in my app. i have a xib which is actually a portrait mode but the image is set up as landscape mode.I just want to display the add as landscape.  Rotation is not enabled in my add.

1. I have two view controller. suppose A and B.  I want to display the i ad as portrait in A(which is first screen) and I want to display the iAd in landscape mode in B. I tried to implement the code provided in apple document. But, Every time either the add does not display or it goes in portrait mode. Can anybody forward me the exact implementation of the code in showing iAd View showing in landscape mode. Thanks in advance.  My app is not uploaded. Somewhere in stack overflow ([iAd Landscape Strange View Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785147/iad-landscape-strange-view-behavior?rq=1) ) I found that in testing mode we can not check with the landscape mode. Kindly guide.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. In my landscape game iOS app which has a few iAds, even though the app is landscape the ads displayed are still portrait. However they are still positioned in the correct orientation on the screen. The thing is I think there are more advertisers using the portrait as rather than the landscape iAd. This you will notice the iAd popup much more in portrait. You could just use the smaller portrait version in a landscape app. It still looks alright for the most part.

Comment: hello man. 1.I could get your answer correctly.  Why m facing  this problem. No apple documentation restricts us to use landscape mode,but in my case its always coming in portrait mode. 2.Is it the problem only because of testing this not distributing?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what's wrong with your app as you have not posted any code. Please post the code were you setup your iAd. 2. I don't think this issue is anything to do with testing if distributing. You can get landscape iAds in testing as well. This error is just down to how you setup your iAd.